# Custom Buttons Android

Tags: android, button, styles

I want to have a very minimal button that is is just a black rectangular box around text. What's the easiest way to do this. Should I make images in Photoshop or just use styles? Can I use styles?

Comment: How would I do it using styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
 <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

create this drawable and set it as background of your button...

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Button" />
```

in your layout file.